# Type-safe linear maybeToList

Tags: idris, idris2

I thought that `maybeToList` would be a good function to try Idris2's linearity feature on. I'm aware that `maybeToVect` would usually be a better choice, but I guess that its implementation wouldn't use the same approach of "linearly using all `a`s in the container".

In linear Haskell, `maybeToList :: Maybe a %1 -> [a]` needs to use the `x` in the `Just x` case linearly, but for Idris2, the following incorrect implementation type-checks:

```
maybeToList : (1 _ : Maybe a) -> List a
maybeToList (Just x) = []
maybeToList Nothing = []
```

What signature can I use in Idris2 to get the same behavior here as with linear Haskell?

For reference, the signature of [maybeToVect](https://github.com/edwinb/Idris2-boot/blob/0fb1192cd30ec4747cbc727f26ddbfad515d1363/libs/base/Data/Vect.idr#L726) in idris-boot also allows incorrect implementations to type-check:

```
maybeToVect : Maybe elem -> (p ** Vect p elem)
maybeToVect Nothing  = (_ ** [])
maybeToVect (Just j) = (_ ** [j])
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the solution is a bit difficult at the moment, because Idris2 [doesn't support multiplicity polymorphism](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/issues/758#issuecomment-717007971):

The libs for Idris2 have both a [linear list](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/main/libs/linear/Data/Linear/LList.idr) and a [linear maybe](https://github.com/idris-lang/Idris2/blob/main/libs/linear/Data/Linear/LMaybe.idr).
When switching my type signature to both of these types, the correct solution is indeed the only one that type-checks.